# Redirect user using the history push in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to redirect user to a page once the success happens.

Now, I have following code where,

So, I have this url ,

```
http://localhost:4000/ws?add=true&id=4123
```

Now on sucess of this ,I am redirecting user to

```
http://localhost:4000/ws?id=2334
```

Now for this what I tried is ,

```
history.push({
        pathname: `/ws/id/${newid}`,
        search: history.location.search
      })
```

which redirects user to the

```
http://localhost:4000/ws/id/2334?id=4123
```

can any one help me with this. why is it taking the previous parameter as well and not redirecting to the one which I am redirecting?

Thanks.

Comment: We are missing context and implementation details. Where does the 2334 come from? It'd be a lot easier to help with snippets of code you are dealing with.

Comment: Actually u can say they are hardcoded values for now.

Comment: The intent is confusing because it's not clear what you are currently doing and what you want to do so it's hard to discern the problem you are having. Also, just because they are hardcoded doesn't really answer the problem. If we're take the question as stated it sounds like you're just asking why the get parameters are forwarded with the redirect. Try just supplying the pathname without the search.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that:

```
history.push(`/ws?id=${newid}`);
```